# Init a new array on instantiation

Tags: ios, objective-c++

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

I have an `Objective-C++` class with these two properties:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int* road;
@property (nonatomic) int* cars;

...

@end
```

And inside `init` method this:

```
    _road = new int[16] (0);
    _cars = new int[16] (0);
```

But I get this error: `Array 'new' cannot have initialization arguments`.

Reading this [tutorial](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/pointers/C++NotInC.html) they said that I can initialize them that way.

**How can I initialize those variables?**

Comment: Why even bother allocating if there is always 16 elements?  Why not `std::vector`?

Comment: @trojanfoe Can I use std library in an iOS project?

Comment: Yup.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix a problem use such code:

```
_road = new int[16] ();
_cars = new int[16] ();
```

It initialises all members of arrays to default value.

Answer (score 1):

ISO C++ does not allow to specify a constructor parameter. The tutorial you linked might refer to a language extension not available in clang.